# Trivial Two-Variable differential equation solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If the initial value from a function $f(x,t)$ is $f_0(x)$, how can I see that the solution to$$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=a\frac {\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x},$$ is something like $$f(x,t)=f_0(x-at).$$

**My attemp:**
I can write $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$ as $$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{f(x,t+\Delta t)-f(x,t)}{\Delta t}$$ and $f(x+\Delta x,t)$ as $$f(x+\Delta x,t)=f(x,t)-a\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$$ achieving $$f(x,t+\Delta t)=f(x+\Delta x,t)+(a \Delta t -\Delta x )\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$$ which seems to be close to the final result.

**Additional content**: If the question seem too superfluous I should say that my actual concern is about checking a result given in the following paper, pg. 181, equation $(4)$:

> Bohm, D. (1952) A Suggested Interpretation of the Quantum Theory in
>   Terms of “Hidden” Variables. Physical Review, 85, 66-179.
>   https://doi.org/10.1103/physrev.85.166

Comment: Transform the PDE under the coordinate change $u=x-at$, $v=x+at$. Which is the same as setting $f(x,t)=g(x-at,x+at)$.

Answer (score 1):

With $a>0$ you can always find for every $f(x,t)$ a function $g(u,v)$ so that $f(x,t)=g(x-at,x+at)$. Then
$$
f_x=g_u+g_v,\; f_t=a(g_v-g_u)
$$
so that the original equation reduces to $g_u=\frac{∂g}{∂u}=0$ which means that $g$ is only a function of $v=x+at$.
With $t=0$ the initial condition is $g(x)=f_0(x)$.